# How to change variables in the yml to install an environment in Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compiler-flags

My knowledge in linux is very limited and I have tried my best but couldn't figure this problem.

There is a python package that I have managed to install on a linux computer by following the installation instructions. I am now trying to install the same in Windows but I can't figure out how to.

This is the [package](https://github.com/armstonj/pylidar-tls-canopy).

I used `miniforge` to create the environment using the yml file.

I installed the the Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 for the C++ compiler.

The following are the variables in the [yml file](https://github.com/armstonj/pylidar-tls-canopy/blob/main/environment.yml) for installation in linux.

```
variables:
RIVLIB_ROOT: /gpfs/data1/vclgp/software/rivlib-2_6_0-x86_64-linux-gcc9
RDBLIB_ROOT: /gpfs/data1/vclgp/software/rdblib-2.4.0-x86_64-linux
PYLIDAR_CXX_FLAGS: -std=c++11
```

I got the appropriate windows equivalent RIVLIB and RDBLIB and changed the paths. I don't understand what to do with the PYLIDAR_CXX_FLAG. I'm guessing this needs to be changed but I have no idea to what.

Comment: it is confusing that you talk about windows then linux then windows again. The question is aobut windows not linux right?

Comment: Sorry about that! Yeah I meant I was able to follow the installation instructions and install the package on Linux, which was straightforward. I am now trying to do it in Windows. In the yml file, I changed the paths RIVLIB_ROOT and RDBLIB_ROOT to corresponding Windows equivalents. I have no idea what to do with the PYLIDAR_CXX_FLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

msvc compiler doesn't support **-std=c++11** flag, instead it has the **/std**, you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170), but the c++11 is supported by default and there is no such switch, so you can just remove it.

Comment: For some time, now (since VS 2017?), the MSVC compiler doesn't support Standards earlier than C++14 (which is the default).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to set the variable in linux before creating the environment using "export PYLIDAR_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11"". In windows, it is done like this, if I am not wrong,  "setx PYLIDAR_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11" /M". Do I ignore this step as well?

Comment: yeah, I think, you can skip this.